# How would you go about creating an interactive grid based on 2 tables in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

The situation needs for me to take one table of Members and put them in the interactive grid, each member may have sub-members that exist in another table, if the member has sub-members then I need to be able to display each sub-member underneath the main member, Will need to be able to also search for data related to a sub-member.

Comment: I'd create master-detail layout, because - what you described - *is* master (members) - details (sub-members) situation.

Comment: Thank you! @Littlefoot will steer research towards that direction

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.